# Is it "restricted to" or "restricted from"?

Tags: meaning, verbs, prepositions, meaning-in-context, collocation

I came across this sentence:

> The power to rule was restricted to ministers, and it was restricted from king.

What is the difference between "restricted to" and "restricted from" here?

Comment: Look at the prepositions *to* and *from* in isolation and then apply the respective meanings to *restricted* in each case. This is no special case.

Comment: You might be interested in our [sister site](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), ELL, which is a good site for basic English questions. Please  have a look at the quick tour of [EL&U](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) to determine where you can best be helped!

Answer (score 2):

**restricted to ministers would** mean powers were limited only to ministers and
**restricted from king** would mean power was seized from king

Answer (score 0):

I'd interpret this passage as, "Only ministers were allowed to rule, and the king was not allowed to rule." "Restricted to" is another way of saying "limited to" and "restricted from" is another way of saying "forbidden to." It's possible, though not standard, for "restricted to" to mean "forbidden to" as well, though, so be careful!